# Loop thru listview Entity Framework

Tags: listview, loops, frameworks, entity

I have a listview populated from a stored procedure in my Entity Framework

I want to iterate thru the listview and display a certain property value.

To do the loop I tried the following code

```
// Loop thru the listview items
for (int i = 0; i < listview1.Items.Count; i++)
{         
    // Item as type of class 'consHead'
    var item = listview1.Items[i] as ConsHead;

    // 'consHead' has a property called 'Enquiry_Number'
    // display this property in a message box
    MessageBox.Show(item.Enquiry_Number);
}
```

but I get 'object reference not set to instance of object

I'm sure the stored procedure works 100% and the listview is populated.
I've tested this by removing the for loop and my listview does display all the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some strugle I found [this](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/64/posts/11620/entity-framework-40-bind-stored-procedure-with-result-entity-class.aspx) article which helped me out.

First of all I had to do the 'Add Function Import' in my Entity Class Designer for the stored procedure I had created. Then I had to create a new complex type during the 'add function' wizard. I called my new Complex type 'ConsHeadRef'.

Now I use the new complex type to set my listview item from instead of the previous 'consHead' type.

```
for (int i = 0; i < listview1.Items.Count; i++)
{         
    var item = listview1.Items[i] as ConsHeadRef;
    MessageBox.Show(item.Enquiry_Number.ToString());
}
```